# d3.select(this).attr() get Undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm try to use `d3.js` `select()` to get id in Html attribute when i was use drag event.
but don't know why I get `null` in my console but the other similar code is work

Here's my code:
1.Html

```
<g transform="translate(765,407)" fill="black"><circle r="15" class="sNodes" id="node_id31" onclick="NodesDown(31)" style="stroke: rgb(41, 194, 244); stroke-width: 5px;"></circle><text dx="-20" dy="50" id="node_id31">1255</text></g>
```

2.JS

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
.on('dragstart', function (d) {
    d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'black');
})
.on('drag', function (d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.x + "," + d3.event.y + ")");
})
.on('dragend', function (d) {
    var id = d3.select(id).attr("id"); //this not work
var trans = d3.select(this).attr("transform"); //this work
});
```

update:
Still doesn't work.

changed:

```
 .on('dragend', function (d) {
        var id = d3.select(id).attr("id"); //this not work
    var trans = d3.select(this).attr("transform"); //this work
    });
```

to:

```
.on('dragend', function (d) {
    var id = d3.select(this).attr("id"); //this not work
var trans = d3.select(this).attr("transform"); //this work
});
```

Comment: You are creating a variable called `id`. so when you call `d3.select(id)` the value of `id` is undefined... what is the expected value of the variable `id`

Comment: is still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the `dragend`. Try replacing it with this.

```
.on('dragend', function (d) {
    var id = d3.select(this).attr("id"); 
    var trans = d3.select(this).attr("transform"); 
});
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you actually bind the drag call?

Comment: Hi @Fawzan here is my code https://jsbin.com/dikakexewu/edit?html,js,output
thanks

Comment: I see no output there? also is it posibble you to move the example to jsfiddle?

Comment: here's the code in  jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aoyw3b3w/  thanks for help.
but in jsfiddle It does not seem have this problem.

Comment: Yep, that's it. So what are you doing wrong in the local environment?

Comment: That i can't figure out.
But after i carefully see the console seem the problem is d3.select(this)  is get <g>.  So i change use jquey children() that i can currently get what i want.